# Multidimensional array in Multidimensional array index C++

Tags: python, c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm implementing an translating a `Python` code to `C++`, however I want to place a Multidimensional array at another Multidimensional array index. The values of first array should be copied to specific index of other 2D array.

Here's my Python Code:

```
var2 = "121"
a = [None for x in xrange(3)]
a[0] = [3,4,5],[6,4,7]
a[1] = [3,9,6],[7,8,7]
a[2] = [4,8,7],[7,6,7]

for x in var2:
    print 'Value:',x,'\t'
```

Here's my C++ Code:

```
 int a1[2][3] = {
        {3,4,5},
        {6,4,7}
    };

    int a2[2][3] = {
        {3,9,6},
        {7,8,7}
    };

    int a3[2][3] = {
        {4,8,7},
        {7,6,7}
    };
```

Now I have an array:

```
int a[3][];
```

I want to copy a1 to `a[0][0]` as in my python code.

My Question is, How can I copy a1,a2,a3 in array a such that:

```
a[0][0] = a1;
a[1][1] = a2;
a[2][2] = a3;
```

Also, the respective `for-loop` for an array index.

Comment: C-arrays are not assignable. You may use `std::array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to directly initialize the array to hold the data is :

```
int a[3][2][3] = {

        {{3,4,5},
        {6,4,7},},

        {{3,9,6},
        {7,8,7},},

        {{4,8,7},
        {7,6,7}}
    };


for( int i=0; i<3; i++ ){
        for( int j=0; j<2; j++ ){
            for( int k=0; k<3; k++ ){
                cout<<a[i][j][k]<<'\t';
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        cout<<endl<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: how do i check for var2 string, where I have char var2[10] = "123";